# Custom Provisioner for storage class

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes

I'm working on a project and encountered some issues. I'm still a beginner with Kubernetes and need some help regarding that.

The code from helm config is as follows:

```
storage:
    storageClass: aws-efs
    provisioner: someCustomName
    pvc:
      logs:
      .........
```

I'm unable to figure out the **provisioner part** there's some custom name written instead of the usual storageclass provisioner such as `kubernetes.io/azure-file`. So, is it a custom provisioner? or it's some different concept? Please, guide me!

I've searched a lot but unable to get anything on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [provisioner](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner) is prefixed with `kubernetes.io/` like [azure-file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#azure-file) it means that it is an *internal provisioner* plugin. But it is valid to use an *external provisioner* as well.

> You are not restricted to specifying the "internal" provisioners listed here (whose names are prefixed with "kubernetes.io" and shipped alongside Kubernetes). You can also run and specify external provisioners, which are independent programs that follow a [specification](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/storage/volume-provisioning.md) defined by Kubernetes. Authors of external provisioners have full discretion over where their code lives, how the provisioner is shipped, how it needs to be run, what volume plugin it uses (including Flex), etc. The repository kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-lib-external-provisioner houses a library for writing external provisioners that implements the bulk of the specification.

Also see more about the [AWS EFS CSI driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped me a lot.

I've done some research on CSI external provisioners. Right now, I would like to use the azure files instead of aws-efs and I've also got the azure files CSI plugin in the github repo. 

What I want to ask is, which approach should I follow to replace the aws-efs with azurefiles. I'm also gonna do the POC first on azurefiles CSI plugin but I would like to know if I'm going into the right direction!?

Comment: And also, why use an external provisioner instead of an internal provisioner? We do have azurefiles internal provisioner `kubernetes.io/azure-file`, so why to use azure files csi plugin?